# What word should I use to describe the "ending/end" of a committee, work group etc?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request

When a body in an organisation is no longer useful it is... Abolished? Discontinued? Terminated? Ended? Closed down..?

And what's the corresponding noun? That is, what words could I use for the verb/noun in the following sentences:

1. In order for a work group or committee to be VERB, the following criteria must be satisfied.
2. NOUN of a work group or committee must be approved by the president.

Comment: If it is no longer useful, it is **dissolved**. For a working group or committee to be active, the following criteria must be met. The agenda of a working group or committee must be approved by the chairman.

Comment: There are probably several words that could be used here. There's no specific term.  Terminated (noun: termination), closed (noun: closure), ended (noun: ending/cessation). dissolved (noun: dissolution), cancelled (noun: cancellation), discontinued (noun: discontinuation),

Comment: The phrase **wound up** is often used in his context. https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/wound%20up

Comment: There is also **abolished / abolition**  or **disbanded / disbanding**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of your provided words are good, I would suggest:

> dissolved/terminated

1. In order for a work group or committee to be dissolved/terminated, the following criteria must be satisfied.
2. Dissolution/Termination of a work group or committee must be approved by the president.